# What happens to /v/ when it's immediately followed by /b/ in American English?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

In phrases like "of books" "have been" and more what happens to that /v/ sound i tried listening online but I can't quite place how exactly it is made. Does it get devoiced or get changed into a plosive? And a more general question: What happens in the consonant clusters xy where x is a front fricative sound and y is a front plosive sound

edit: would this be correct: of books: ʌbˈbʊks

Comment: Anecdotally, it seems I devoice  in "of books" but not "have been."

Comment: I would think the answer to this question would depend greatly on regional dialect, not to mention American vs. British pronunciation.

Comment: @RobJarvis what about in your own dialect?

Comment: In the southern US where I live, there seems to be some variation. Typically, I hear people devoicing things like "of books", contracting to "ʌbˈbʊks"; on the other hand, most people here will contract the "have" in "have been" to "I've been," "They've been," etc., to the point that many misspell "I could have been" in writing, rendering "I could of been." Clearly, those people are in the habit of pronouncing the /v/ sound.

Comment: The /v/ sound occurring at the end of "of" and "have" is made while a person closes their mouth.   The /b/ sound occurring at the beginning of "books" and "been" is made while a person opens their mouth.

Comment: Some dialects won't pronounce the v at all (commonly written "o' books").

Comment: /vb/ is a figment of literate imagination. Native speakers don't speak anywhere near that clearly.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where you’re from and the tone of the conversation. In the Great Plains and with a semi-formal tone, the /v/ stays intact, with a gap between the two words. The same applies to the general question: XY would be split in two.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This, along with the comment by @RobJarvis, get it (so go back to sleep, Community Bot). You can't come up with a universal rule for this. In California, where I live, the /v/ and /b/ are generally pretty strong; nothing much happens to them. But California is a big place, and so even in this one state people might pronounce words a little differently.